# Integration function with matrix parameter

Tags: integration, matrices, matrix-calculus

Let's asumme some integrable function $f (t,x)$ with respect to $t $ and some parameter $x,a,b \in \mathbb{R} $. In such way $\int_b^a f (t,x)dt =F (a,x)-F (b,x) $

Let's assume that we know closed form solution for $F (x,a) $ and $F (x,b) $. Is it true that equation will holds true for all square n×n matrices  $X, A,B$ written instead of $x,a,b $

**example**: $\int_b^a t^x dt =\frac {a^{x+1}-b^{x+1}}{x+1} $. You can write that solution as Taylor series so for matrix substitution it will have some vlaid results. For example $e^A =\sum_{k=0}^{\infty} \frac {A^k}{k!}$ is treat as definition. In such way what I want to ask in that scenario is it sufficient to get closed form solution of integral to write

$\displaystyle \int_b^a t^x dt =\frac {a^{x+1}-b^{x+1}}{x+1} \Rightarrow \int_B^A t^X dt=\frac {A^{X+1}-B^{X+1}}{X+1} $

PS: My knowledge about matrices is $\epsilon>0 $ so if there are any issues please correct me.

Comment: Imagine that $F(a,x) = \frac{1}{a + \lvert x \rvert }$. What meaning will you give to $F(A,X)$ if $A,X$ are matrices?

Comment: Just write it as Taylor series and count it. This is for example definition for matrix $e^A $

Comment: The integration variable $t$ is a **scalar** quantity, but $(A,B)$ are matrices so they cannot represent the limits of integration.

Comment: And what about $a+bi=\begin{bmatrix}a&-b\\b&a\end{bmatrix}$. Technically it is different way to represent the same thing. So matrix boundry of integration could have some kind of sense I guess

Answer (score 1):

The answer is no, because if you want to take into account matrix-dependent functions you have to readapt the meaning of the boundary of your integration interval. To be clearer, in your case you have that $\partial[a,b]=\{a,b\}$. If you let $T$ belongs to $\Omega\subset\mathbb{R}^{n\times n}$ for example you have to expect to obtain something related to the boundary of $\Omega$. The generalisation you are looking for is the "Generalized Stokes theorem". And possible restrictions regard the regularity and the nature of $\partial\Omega$.

Comment: Ok, don't gonna lie. I am very weak in matrices. So I will precize some things. Let's give example $\int_b^a t^x dt =\frac {a^{x+1}-b^{x+1}}{x+1} $. You can write that solution as Taylor series, so there were no exponents. And for simplifity let's assume matrices $X,A,B $ are all n×n.  In such way $\frac {A^{X+1}-B^{X+1}}{X+1} $ will be posible to count as matrix. And this is what I exacly mean

Comment: First of all you should define $A^B$ when $A,B$ are matrices. Probably you could consider a definition like the following $A^B:=\exp(B\cdot \log A)$ but I don't know which kind of properties you can get. After that, considering $A,B,X\in\mathbb{R}^{n\times n}$ and the segment $[A,B]:=\{At+(1-t)B\;:\;t\in[0,1]\}$ you can give a meaning to that integral because it would be the integral on this segment in $\mathbb{R}^{n\times n}$.